# How do I set XAConnectionFactoryEnabled in WLST Offline Mode

Tags: jms, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I am trying to set up a JMS queue in Weblogic to be transactional. This requires enabling XA on the connection factory I am using.

I know I can do this from the admin console once weblogic is up and running. However, I really need to do it in offline mode while the domain is being created. Right now I have this:

```
#*Setting up resources and JDBC*
cd('/')
create('JMSServer-0', 'JMSServer')
cd('/')
create('JMSQueues', 'JMSSystemResource')
cd('JMSSystemResource/JMSQueues/JmsResource/NO_NAME_0')

queue=create('AQueue', 'Queue')
queue.setJNDIName('jms/AQueue')
queue.setSubDeploymentName('subdeploymentA')

queue=create('BQueue', 'Queue')
queue.setJNDIName('jms/BQueue')
queue.setSubDeploymentName('subdeploymentB')

connFact=create('AConnFact', 'ConnectionFactory')
connFact.setJNDIName('jms/AConnFact')
connFact.setSubDeploymentName('subdeployment_fact_A')

connFact=create('BConnFact', 'ConnectionFactory')
connFact.setJNDIName('jms/BConnFact')
connFact.setSubDeploymentName('subdeployment_fact_B')

cd('/JMSSystemResource/JMSQueues/JmsResource/NO_NAME_0/ConnectionFactory/BConnFact')
tp=create('BConnFactTp', 'TransactionParam')
tp.setXAConnectionFactoryEnabled(true)

#TransactionParam does not show up here
print "\n" + pwd() + "\n"
ls()

#TransactionParam DOES show up here
cd('/JMSSystemResource/JMSQueues/JmsResource/NO_NAME_0/ConnectionFactory/AConnFact')
print "\n" + pwd() + "\n"
ls()

#Finalization follows here
```

Now, this is an existing script and AConnFact and AQueue have been around for awhile with XA disabled, so I'd prefer to leave them alone. So, how do I make it so that BConnFact is actually the one that gains the new TransactionParam settings?

I should note that I do have a "meh" fix to this. Create will place the TransactionParams in the order that the ConnectionFactories are created. I can just place them in the order I want. However, I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

See if something like the following example will work for you:

```
cd('/JMSSystemResources/MyModule/JMSResource/MyModule')
cmo.createConnectionFactory('MyConnFac')
cd('/JMSSystemResources/MyModule/JMSResource/MyModule/ConnectionFactories/MyConnFac')
cmo.setJNDIName('jms/MyConnFac')
cmo.setSubDeployment('my_sub')
cd('/JMSSystemResources/MyModule/JMSResource/MyModule/ConnectionFactories/MyConnFac/TransactionParams/MyConnFac')
cmo.setTransactionTimeout(3600)
cmo.setXAConnectionFactoryEnabled(true)
```

Works for us in 10.3.6

Edit: Ah probably. If you really need to do it offline and wlst isn't going to work you can manually edit your `<domain home>/config/jms/<jms module>.xml` file and add

```
<transaction-params>
  <transaction-timeout>900</transaction-timeout>
  <xa-connection-factory-enabled>true</xa-connection-factory-enabled>
</transaction-params>
```

under your connection factory.

Comment: I have seen code snippets similar to that (making use of cmo). I have previously tried inserting it into the script and had no luck. So I just tried doing that through use of the WLST command line prompt (as opposed to in the script). Getting an error stating "Error: only getter and setter are supported".

Explains why it didn't work in the script. Though this is confusing to me since create works...

Comment: Perhaps cmo being unable to create is a limitation of WLST offline.

Comment: See added edit to answer. Maybe that is a possible workaround for now.

Comment: Right now I have the workaround I mentioned in my edit. 

Unfortunately,  I really need to have it done during the creation of the connection factories (I'm changing a script that's part of a larger setup that's used by a bunch of people, so I'm trying to avoid using the admin console or any other manual edits).

Thank you for the help though.

Comment: So why does the server have to be down? If it's not a "live" update why can't you just change a file?

Comment: 1) Environment-based limitations.

2) Doesn't that file change on deployment based on the specifications in the WLST scripts? If so, wouldn't that require modifying the file every time something is redeployed?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit outdated but in offline this works for 12.2.1:

```
connFact = create('PubSubSelectorsConnectionFactory','ConnectionFactory')
connFact.setJNDIName('jms/PubSubSelectorsConnectionFactory')
cd('/JMSSystemResource/PubSubSelectorsJMSModule/JmsResource/NO_NAME_0/ConnectionFactory/PubSubSelectorsConnectionFactory')
set('DefaultTargetingEnabled','true')
create('PubSubSelectorsConnectionFactoryTP', 'TransactionParams')
cd('TransactionParams/NO_NAME_0')
set('XAConnectionFactoryEnabled', 'true')
```